Smallest integer $n$ so that $\tan(5\pi/16) - 2\tan(\pi/8) = \tan(n\pi/16)$
So the question goes like this:
If $\tan(5π/16) - 2\tan(π/8) = \tan(nπ/16)$, then smallest positive integer n is equal to ?
Try 1:
I tried simplifying the LHS in terms of $\pi/16$ by converting $\tan(\pi/8)$ into $\pi/16$ using the double angle formula but couldn't make it out.
Try 2:
We know $\tan(\pi/8) = \sqrt2 -1$. I used it to find $\tan(\pi/16)$, but it doesn't fit.
An approach using simplification is encouraged.

Hint: $\cot x - 2\cot (2x)=\tan x$ and $\tan(5\pi/16)=\cot(3\pi/16)$ and $\tan(\pi/8)=\cot(3\pi/8)$.

MathJax hint:  if you put a backslash before common functions you get the right font and spacing, so \tan x gives $\tan x$ instead of tan x which gives $tan x$

It is easy enough to find on a calculator using tan() and atan() buttons.  Even if this is insufficient in the answer to your question, it should point you in a useful direction.  Incidentally,    $\tan(\pi/16) = \sqrt{\frac{2 - \sqrt{2 + \sqrt 2}}{2 + \sqrt{2 + \sqrt 2}}}=\sqrt{2(2 + \sqrt 2)}-1-\sqrt 2$ and it may also be worth finding  $\tan(5\pi/16)$ and its reciprocal $\tan(3\pi/16)$

Oh thanks @RossMillikan. Shall use it from now onwards.

Claim: $\cot x - 2\cot(2x)=\tan x$
Proof: $$\cot x - \tan x = \frac{\cos x}{\sin x} - \frac{\sin x}{\cos x} = \frac{\cos^2 x -\sin^2 x}{\sin x\cos x} =\frac{2\cos (2x)}{\sin(2x)}=2\cot(2x)$$
Then take $x = \frac{3\pi}{16}$ and use that $\cot(x)=\tan\left(\frac{\pi}2-x\right)$

A good observation is that
$$\tan(\frac{5π}{16})=\tan(\fracπ4+\frac{π}{16})=\frac{1+\tan(\frac{π}{16})}{1-\tan(\frac{π}{16})}$$
And
$$2\tan(\fracπ8)=\frac{4\tan(\frac{π}{16})}{1-\tan^2(\frac{π}{16})}$$
Subtracting them gives
$$\frac{(1-\tan(\frac{π}{16}))^2}{1-\tan^2(\frac{π}{16})}=\frac{1-\tan(\frac{π}{16})}{1+\tan(\frac{π}{16})}=\tan(\frac{π}{4}-\frac{π}{16})=\tan(\frac{3π}{16})$$
So $n=3$
Minimum value is $3$ because the angle we get lies in the interval $(-\fracπ2,\fracπ2)$ which is the principal domain of $\tan x$
